# Dart Adding a new key value to map

Tags: dart

How do I add a new key value to an existing map? I've searched but nowhere seem to answer for my example. My map looks like this:

```
myMap = {A: {b:3}}
```

I'm simply trying to add key values into 'A' so it looks like this:

```
{A: {b:3, c:3}}
```

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main() {
  var myMap = {'A': {'b':3}};
  myMap['A']!['c'] = 3;
  print(myMap);
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter thanks for responding. Could you take a look at the comment I made to Apealed?

Comment: This code is doing what you asked, updating `A` with a new key-value pair (`c` - `3`).

Comment: Ohh I see now! Sorry I didn't understand that syntax, thank you Peter!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you started with:

```
var myMap = {'A': {'b': 3}};
```

You can update like this:

```dart
myMap['A'] = {
  'b': 3,
  'c': 3,
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I'm trying to append the map inside 'A' while keeping the original. Is this possible? Sorry I'm explaining this badly I think. Basically when I click a button I want the Map to add the new key value inside 'A' while keeping the others there too.

Comment: Peter's answer seems to accomplish that